# "Jumanji" and "Zathura" series

Tags: jumanji, zathura

I have seen the 1995 movie *Jumanji* and also *Zathura* from 2005.

I would like to know if any new part of this series were made till now or not.

Comment: In what sense? The Polar Express was also based on the same author's book, if that counts? If you mean board games, then no.

Comment: I am talking about that magical game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Jumanji* and *Zathura* are both based on books by [Chris Van Allsburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Van_Allsburg). The only other book of his that has been adapted into a film is *The Polar Express*, which is not about a magical board game.

Comment: Ok, I was expecting another part of zathura as it was a very nice movie.

Comment: @bogojane given that it [lost money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura_(film)#Box_office), I wouldn't hold my breath...